# Why I cannot receive the Notification

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kNotificationForbidAdvPost object:nil];
```

I define postNotificationName:kNotificationForbidAdvPost in a .h file

Im my subclass of NSApplication, I import this .h file. And have a observer of this Notification

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(changeToRecordingStatus) name:kNotificationForbidAdvPost object:nil];
```

I am sure that the observer was added first, and then post the notification.

And I see the [UINotification default] in Debug. It have same memory address in two part of code.

Is there some mistake I have?

Thanks!

Comment: dumb question, but... are you sure you have already registered for the notification when it is posted?

Comment: i am sure. And in debug mode, it is showed that two parts of code was run in Thread1.

Comment: how are you defining `kNotificationForbidAdvPost`? do you get any compiler warnings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have try that add a arugument, but it is still not worked.

I create a new project and use a no-argument function to response Notification, it is worked normally.

The reason why I cannot receive the Notification is that a removeObserver method was called at one part which I didn't notice.

Thanks for all your reply.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation is pretty clear when it states that

> The method specified by
>   notificationSelector must have one and
>   only one argument (an instance of
>   NSNotification).

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000219-CHDCIGGB

So, I see your selector you are registering is `changeToRecordingStatus` when it must be `changeToRecordingStatus:`

```
- (void) changeToRecordingStatus: (NSNotification *) notification;
```

Comment: looks like we posted the same answer almost simultaneously, you won by a few seconds though :) - I'll delete my post

Comment: yeah I missed that to until I was just writing a method that accepted a notification, came back to check on this question... sure enough you guys where on it.